Junit Arguments.of() not accepting Java's Consumer interface implementation
This compiles

    public static Stream argumentProvider() {
     Consumer<Instant> consumer = (i)-> Assert.assertNotNull(i);

        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("2024-11-06 00:00:00",13,-2, consumer)
        );
    }

But this does not, why? And how to fix it?
    public static Stream argumentProvider() {
     Consumer<Instant> consumer = (i)-> Assert.assertNotNull(i);

        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("2024-11-06 00:00:00",13,-2,  (i)-> Assert.assertNotNull(i))
        );
    }

Above(second version

Similar situation: Why can't the var keyword in Java be assigned a lambda expression?. Basically, the compiler doesn't have enough information to know which functional interface you're trying to implement in your second version.

Type Inference Weakness
The compiler's type inference system is unable to accurately deduce the type in this specific scenario.
In cases where the compiler's type inference system is unable to accurately deduce the type, explicitly annotating the type expressions can help guide the compiler. You can provide an explicit type declaration to guide the compiler's inference process.
Example:
Stream.of(
    Arguments.of(
      2024-11-06 00:00:00",
      13,
      -2,
      (Consumer<Instant>) Assertions::assertNotNull));

